# Eclipse : Link with editor keyboard shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Link with editor" feature in Eclipse?

if not, is there any way, where i can map ui elements on eclipse with keyboard shortcuts? (custom plugins/RCP code etc?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is not by default, but you can define this yourself. Go into Preferences -> General -> Keys, and then type "link" into the search box. You want the "Toggle Link with Editor" command. You can then define the key binding by filling in the "Binding" box below.

Comment: I define the binding, something like CTRL+SHIFT+O, but it doesn't work :(... (tried other bindings). Any idea why? (I have "In Window" as shortcut context, suing eclipse Luna)

Comment: If you use the latest eclipse press Ctrl + 3 and type 'Keys' to reach the key binding menu. No need to navigate through the menus anymore. Use Cmd+3 for mac.

Comment: @edbras You're right, it seems like it only works whe you're focused in the "Package explorer" tile which is a bummer. The same behavior is present in the 2018-12 release.

Comment: @jebeaudet You can focus on "Package Explorer" first by using Alt + Shift Q, E shortcut and then use the new binding. Alternatively you can focus on "Project Explorer" and use the new binding, but "Show View (Project Explorer)" has no default binding and you have to define one first.