# How to locate current file in Eclipse Project Explorer view using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: java, eclipse

As a user of ReSharper in Visual Studio, I find the [Locate in Solution Explorer](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Locating_a_File_in_Solution_Explorer.html) shortcut, (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), immensely useful. Is there an equivalent in Eclipse to locate the current file in the Project Explorer?

A Google search and a quick root around in the Keys preferences window suggested there wasn't, but perhaps I just couldn't find it.

Comment: You can use the "Link with Editor" button (two arrows) above the Tree.

Comment: A cursory search on Google found this:

http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/01/06/instantly-show-a-classfile-in-the-packageproject-explorer-in-eclipse/

Comment: Seems my Google-Fu failed me this time - slightly different terminology :) Thanks all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default setting is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. But you can set any key combination you like to the command "Show In (Project Explorer)" from the Preferences | General | Keys dialog.

Comment: What is the name of the "navigation" menu that appears on ALT+SHIFT+W ? Thanks for the tips, didn't know it (a shortcut fan)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about a shortcut key, but there is a small button in the "Package Explorer" toolbar with two arrows. If you press that toggle button then the Package Explorer will select the currently editing file.

Similar for the Project Explorer view.

Answer (score 2):

If you press the buttons <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> you get access to open a resource in a project.  If you then have the two double arrows clicked in the project explorer, you will go straight to that file.

Answer (score 2):

answer is here
[Eclipse : Link with editor keyboard shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415661/eclipse-link-with-editor-keyboard-shortcut)

There is not by default, but you can define this yourself. Go into Preferences -> General -> Keys, and then type "link" into the search box. You want the "Toggle Link with Editor" command. You can then define the key binding by filling in the "Binding" box below.